# Активность разделов бокового меню в зависимости от положение страницы

Tags: jquery, javascript

Например в сайдбаре у нас есть 5 разделов. Назовем их "Пункт 1", "Пункт 2", "Пункт 3", "Пункт 4" и "Пункт 5". Контентная часть разбита на (естесственно) 5 разделов с заголовками соответсвующим сайдбару и каким то текстом. Задача состоит в том чтобы кидать на раздел в сайдбаре какой нить класс аля "active", когда мы находимся на этом тексте. Доходим до второго текста и "активность" меняется. Контентные блоки могут быть разной высоты, поэтому сделать фиксированно не получится. хелп!

Comment: Либо пронумеруйте блоки с контентом одинаково с пунктами, либо сделайте схожие названия классов, а потом отслеживайте положение блоков с контентом относительно низа окна браузера.

Answer (score 2):

Подключите [jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#about) и напишите обработчик нужного события.

Answer (score 1):

Набросал вам [возможный вариант реализации](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/97zFj/1/). Там же прокомментировал. В общем, ничего сложного и думаю, что разберетесь.

Comment: Array.prototype.getIndex=function() {}

не надо так делать. никогда. гораздо гуманнее просто функцию в том же замыкании определить,

Comment: небольшая демонстрация почему именно не делать http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/qypPM/